# C++ Need help getting user input for String Frequency Program

Tags: c++

Here is my code. I have to write a program that takes user input for a string and displays the frequency of each letter in that string. I get this as an error no matter what I do. What would be the proper way to get user input for this code. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!:

```
error: array must be initialized with a brace-enclosed initializer
```

.

```
    int main()
{
    string input;
    cin >> input;
   char freq[100] = input;
   int c = 0, count[26] = {0};
   while ( freq[c] != '\0' )
   {

      if ( freq[c] >= 'a' && freq[c] <= 'z' )
         count[freq[c]-'a']++;
      c++;
   }

   for ( c = 0 ; c < 26 ; c++ )
   {
      if( freq[c] != 0 )
         printf("%c occurs %d times in the entered string.\n",c+'a',count[c]);
   }
}
```

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: @ EJoshuaS - Reinstate Monica 
error: array must be initialized with a brace-enclosed initializer

Comment: `string input` and `char string[100]`. You don't see a problem with naming a variable the same as a type? Also, the compiler tells you exactly what line is causing the problem, but you've failed to provide the actual error message that identifies that line.

Comment: @Ken White I can see how that would be problematic I planned on changing it after I had the program working

Comment: What exactly do you expect to accomplish with `char freq[100] = input;`? `input` is already a perfectly valid `std::string`, that contains perfectly valid input. Copying it to a plain char array (after crossing your fingers hoping that it's less than 100 characters -- even if this is done right), accomplishes nothing useful whatsoever. Everything that can be posibbly done with an old-style `char` array can also be done with a `std::string`.

Comment: @Sam Varshavchik I am more familiar with using char arrays than std::string. I'm still very new to C++ but it seems like std::string would be better to use in this situation. I'm also not sure how I would incorporate std::string into my code.

Answer (score 0):

Using std::string is better than old-style char!In fact,you should use those knowledge u r not familiar still.

But if u want to use char now,you can remove variable input.u can change first three lines in main() function to this:

```
char freq[100];
cin >> freq;
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I am now able to get input for freq. Sam is definitely right about using std::string and I think I will work on incorporating that into my code.

Answer (score 0):

Hey I think I found the answer to my question:

```
 #include <iostream>
#include <string.h>

using namespace std;

   int main()
{
   string input;
   cout<<"Enter lowercase string: ";
   cin>>input;
   cout<<"Number of characters in string: "<<input.size()<<"\n";
   std::string freq = input;
   int c = 0, count[26] = {0};
   for (std::string::size_type i = 0; i < input.size(); i++) 
   {

      if ( freq[i] >= 'a' && freq[i] <= 'z' ){
         count[freq[i]-'a']++;
      }
      c++;
   }


   for ( c = 0 ; c < 26 ; c++ )
   {
      if( count[c] != 0 )
         printf("%c occurs %d times in the entered string.\n",c+'a',count[c]);
   }
}
```